# How to check for accept4 using CMake

Tags: function, macros, cmake

I am checking for accept4 on Linux like this:

```
check_symbol_exists(accept4 sys/socket.h HAVE_ACCEPT4)
```

However, accept4 is only defined if _GNU_SOURCE is defined beforehand. How can I force the checker to defined _GNU_SOURCE before the check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE)` before calling `check_symbol_exists()` and `list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE)` to cleanup after the check.

Comment: You may find this link useful: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/cmake/config-ix.cmake?view=markup